# Custom animation on fragments, but selective

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have base class for all Fragments and overrided method `onCreateAnimation` to use custom animations at all once, but need to exclude some fragment(s). I did it using `instanceof` but i use nested fragments and it does work as expected. Is an elegant way to disable animation for some fragments in this situation ?

```
abstract public class BaseFragment<T> extends Fragment {
    public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
       if(this instanceof ScannerFragment) {
          return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim);
       } else {
          // custom animation
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try initiating the fragments with a parameter that enables or disables the animation:

```
public static BaseFragment newInstance(boolean isAnimated) {
    BaseFragment myFragment = new BaseFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean("isAnimated", isAnimated);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

In your activity, you create the fragment by calling BaseFragment.newInstance(true/false);

In your Fragment code you can then use `getArguments().getBoolean("isAnimated", true);` to get the value that you passed.

Comment: I recognize fragments by type, no need to pass another argument. Another argument does't resolve a problem.

Comment: Then can you add some more information as to what does not work as expected? The identification of the fragments or the animation on the nested fragments?